# How to sort Dates by per week in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am iOS developer and I need to filter date array by weeks date.
Ex: Response

```
stepsList =     (
                {
            date = "2015-07-01T00:00:00Z";
            value = 6872;
        },
                {
            date = "2015-08-02T00:00:00Z";
            value = 10309;
        },
                {
            date = "2015-07-10T00:00:00Z";
            value = 10045;
        },
                {
            date = "2015-07-012T00:00:00Z";
            value = 7131;
        },
                {
            date = "2015-07-18T00:00:00Z";
            value = 7376;
        },
                {
            date = "2015-07-27T00:00:00Z";
            value = 4303;
        }
    );
```

from above response expected result i.e.:

```
Week1 =  (2015-07-01,2015-08-02)
Week2 =  (2015-07-10,2015-08-12)
Week3 =  (2015-07-18)
Week4 =  (2015-07-27)
```

etc.

Comment: what exactly is weeks date? Could you be more clear?

Comment: ...and where have you been stuck during the procedure...?

Comment: this is not sorting, but grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a generic answer for you and for future reference, of course, to organise random dates based on date is on which week in the month.

I guess, after a minimal changes you can insert the snippet into your code.

---

## step 0.

so, firstly I would create some random dates and I put them into an array, that will be the actual input which I will sort in a minute.

```
NSMutableArray *_randomDates = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    [_randomDates addObject:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:arc4random_uniform(365) * 24 * 3600]];
}
```

*NOTE: you may use any other procedure to populate an array with dates, you can even populate that array from your original input; or you would skip this step if you have an array with dates already. I am working with random dates to present a pure generic solution here.*

---

## step 1.

I define a standard date-formatter which gives me the date's week of month.

```
NSDateFormatter *_dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
_dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"W";
```

*NOTE: you can read more about date-formatter [in the Apple's Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html).*

---

## step 2.

the main attraction comes now, I create a standard grouped-collection of the random dates.

```
#define kWeekWithFormatSpecifier @"week%@"

NSMutableDictionary *_sortedDates = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[_randomDates enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDate * date, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *_weekString = [_dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSString *_key = [NSString stringWithFormat:kWeekWithFormatSpecifier, _weekString];
    NSMutableArray *_weekArray = [_sortedDates objectForKey:_key];
    if (_weekArray == nil) _weekArray = [NSMutableArray array], [_sortedDates setValue:_weekArray forKey:_key];
    [_weekArray addObject:date];
}];
```

---

## step 3.

last but not least, I sort the individual collections, to get a more sophisticated result.

```
[_sortedDates enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString * key, NSMutableArray * obj, BOOL *stop) {
    [obj sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
}];
```

---

## what we got eventually

after logging:

```
NSLog(@"%@", _sortedDates);
```

the actual result looks promising to me:

```
{
    week1 =     (
        "2015-09-01 10:12:36 +0000",
        "2015-12-04 10:12:36 +0000",
        "2016-02-01 10:12:36 +0000",
        "2016-06-01 10:12:36 +0000"
    );
    week2 =     (
        "2016-05-12 10:12:36 +0000",
        "2016-06-07 10:12:36 +0000",
        "2016-06-10 10:12:36 +0000"
    );
    week3 =     (
        "2016-01-13 10:12:36 +0000",
        "2016-02-16 10:12:36 +0000",
        "2016-03-14 10:12:36 +0000",
        "2016-04-16 10:12:36 +0000",
        "2016-05-15 10:12:36 +0000"
    );
    week4 =     (
        "2015-08-17 10:12:36 +0000",
        "2015-09-23 10:12:36 +0000",
        "2015-11-22 10:12:36 +0000",
        "2015-11-27 10:12:36 +0000",
        "2015-11-28 10:12:36 +0000",
        "2016-03-20 10:12:36 +0000",
        "2016-05-26 10:12:36 +0000",
        "2016-06-20 10:12:36 +0000"
    );
    week5 =     (
        "2015-08-23 10:12:36 +0000",
        "2015-08-24 10:12:36 +0000",
        "2015-08-27 10:12:36 +0000",
        "2016-02-28 10:12:36 +0000",
        "2016-03-30 10:12:36 +0000"
    );
}
```

*NOTE: yes, there can be up to 5 different weeks in a month. additionally I don't worry about formatting the result, that can be part of the post processing procedure, which is up to you from this point.*